# How to programmatically zoom in highcharts?

Tags: graph, charts, zooming, highcharts

When calling axis.setExtremes() or axis.zoom(), the associated zoom button does not become highlighted.

For example, if I programatically 'zoom' to 1-hour, I would like the '1 hour' zoom button to appear as 'pressed'.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

For more context: I want to make my app stately, so that if you view a graph, zoom, then navigate away from the graph and back to it again, I want to restore your 'zoom level'.

I have this basically working by listening for afterSetExtremes and storing the max/min values, and then using those to call 'zoom' on the graph when the user returns.

If there is a simpler way to accomplish this, I'd be fine with that.

Thanks for any direction!

Comment: Is this not what `rangeSelector.selected` is for? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I see that I can set the 'selected' attribute of the rangeSelector. However, how do I know which button index I want? When I handle the afterSetExtremes event, I save the begin and end dates. Is there a button index or button text or something that I can save as well, so that I know which button should be selected? Or do I have to calculate the difference between the begin and end date and go from there?

Comment: `rangeSelector.selected` is read/write, so on your page exit event you could just make a note of whichever button was 'pressed' and then 'press' it again when your user comes back

Comment: Thanks, Paul. In the afterSetExtremes handler, every handle I can get to the chart object still has the previously selected button in the rangeSelector.selected property. Do you know how I can get the newly selected button index off of some event related to the button push? I can't just do this on page exit, because we have a nested structure of iFrames and it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Looking at highStock.src.js, `rangeSelector.setSelected()` is called immediately **after** `setExtremes()` - you could try reversing the order of these two statements. They appear lines 20774 to 20784 in Highstock v2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You can also call setState on the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/W56P5/2/

```
chart.rangeSelector.buttons[3].setState(2);
```